# How to display an iframe by clicking a button (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to display an iframe when a button is clicked. I got the following JS code:

```js
function show() {
    var iframe1 = document.getElementById('iframe');
    iframe1.style.display = 'block';
}
```

and here is the HTML of my page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="buttons.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="paragraphs.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iframes.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="files.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form> <button id="files" onclick="show()">Files</button> </form>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="files.html" width="200" height="100"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

The script is inside an external file named files.js. When I test the code, it works, but the iframe only shows for 1 milisecond. What's wrong?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `type="button"` to your `<button>`. As it is right now, it is inside a form, and without any type attribute — that way it defaults to type `submit`, so when you click it, the page is submitted and disappears.

Also, change `onclick="show()"` to `onclick="show"`, or better yet — use `.addEventListener()` instead.

```js
function show() {
    var iframe1 = document.getElementById('iframe');
    iframe1.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="buttons.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="paragraphs.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iframes.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="files.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form> <button type="button" id="files" onclick="show">Files</button> </form>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="files.html" width="200" height="100"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Additional code in response to OP's comment:

```js
var iframeShowing = false;

function show() {
    var iframe1 = document.getElementById('iframe');
    iframe1.style.display = iframeShowing ? 'block' : 'none';
    iframeShowing = !iframeShowing;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. However, for some obscure reason I had to keep the `onclick="show()"`, otherwise it would not work.

Comment: Also how can I make the iframe hide using the same button?

Answer (score 1):

The form is causing a page reload. You can stop that by simply adding a event.preventDefault(). `function show(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

However, you will need to inject the event parameter in the function call.
`onclick="show(event)"`

Another option you have is just remove the form tag and keep the button tag. That should do the trick.